# .NET Core MVC - Session Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

This is more of a discussion as I am attempting to figure out the cleanest way to get/store/check a data object in *.NET Core MVC*

The scenario is as such:

**The Issue**

User Logs into webapp -> Service fires that creates a User Object (Strongly Typed List)
This user object controls how the app looks and feels and all data in the list is static.

This list is assigned to a ViewBag and used on a Razor page.

The only issue is with every subsequent page change or refresh the User Object is pulled again.

Some people might not think its that bad, but this object generally takes around 7 seconds to fire back to the client rendering the page and on every page that starts to get pretty painful!

**Purposed Solution**

So my theory was, load the User Model once, include a DateTime field called "LastLoaded" and then write the user model with the current date time to some form of session storage in MVC.

Then have some code on each page that checks the LastLoaded field and if the datediff is say greater than 10 minutes, reload the User Object.

So what I will need to know is the best method of storing a List object in MVC and having it survive page loads and refreshes. How then to retrieve that user object and apply it to say a ViewBag.

I am very open to suggestions, even if my premise is flawed and there are far better ways of achieving this. Just let me know if you have faced this issue in the past and what solutions you implemented.

Caz

Comment: What about instead of passing in the dataset in the ViewBag having it loaded by a separate service call once the page is loaded? It sounds like you're wanting to offload the management of this data to the client side so it would make more sense for the client to be responsible for getting/managing this data(be it as a cookie or other internal storage)

Comment: Hey @AllMadHare I have done that for a host of other things, using API calls and local storage. Though if I do that for the User object it sort of renders razor useless, that is my main concern that in doing it that way I am practically using a HTML webpage and jquery with a Web API project in the background. I am also concerned once I go to localstorage using js I loose my strong models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Session, I would recommend using distributed cache. Distributed cache such as Redis or NCache http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/ or AppFabric Cache. These technologies are designed specially to handle such situation and they have libraries for easy integration. By using distributed cache, you make your application and cache independently scalable. And they also come with performance tools to monitor the usage and performance of cache.

Ideally, I would keep object in cache, and when I am modifying the object, I would go ahead and put object in cache after modification, assuming I would be immediately accessing it again.

These cache come with various settings of cache timeouts, so older objects which are not accessed frequently will be removed automatically.

Though session is per user and cache is for everyone, you can easily change your cache key by prefixing it with the user id.

Comment: Wow this looks pretty full on, going to have to do a heap of reading up on this stuff as I have not touched it before. On the surface it looks like what I am wanting to do, so I will mark correct. Time to hit the books on this stuff!